# Bing Maps is not updating the GUI after changing ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bing-maps, bing

I am using **MVVM** and **Bing Maps**.

**Task**: after we have drawn the polyline on the map (MapHandle.cs: **List  ViewFieldList**), click the button (MapHandle.xaml: **ButtonAddingField**) and it adds new polylines to the **Model** via **FieldCollectionViewModel**. Moreover, the Bing Maps map has **ItemsSource = "{Binding FieldList}"**.

**Problem**: Map does not add a polyline after updating Model.

**Model - Field.cs**

```
public class Field {
    public LocationCollection LocList { get; set; }

    public Field(MapPolyline polyline)
    {
        LocList = polyline.Locations;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel1 - FieldCollectionViewModel.cs**

```
internal class FieldCollectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Public Properties

    public ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel> FieldList { get; set ; }

    #endregion Public Properties

    #region Constructor

    public FieldCollectionViewModel()
    {
        FieldList = new ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel>();
    }

    public FieldCollectionViewModel(List<Field> fields)
    {
        FieldList = new ObservableCollection<FieldViewModel>(fields.Select(f => new FieldViewModel(f)));
    }

    private DelegateCommand<object> addFieldCommand;

    public ICommand AddFieldCommand {
        get {
            if (addFieldCommand == null) addFieldCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(AddNewField);
            return addFieldCommand;
        }
    }

    private void AddNewField(object parameter)
    {
        ((List<MapPolyline>)parameter).ForEach(i =>
       {
           var ff = new Field(i);
           FieldList.Add(new FieldViewModel(ff));
       });

        ((List<MapPolyline>)parameter).Clear();

    }

    #endregion Constructor
```

**ViewModel2 - FieldViewModel.cs**

```
internal class FieldViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Constructor

    public FieldViewModel(Field field)
    {
        Field = field;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public Field Field;

    public LocationCollection LocList
    {
        get => Field.LocList;
        set
        {
            Field.LocList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocList));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

BaseVewModel: PropertyChanged functionality

View - MapHandle.xaml

```
   <m:Map
        x:Name="myMap"
        Mode="AerialWithLabels"
        MouseMove="myMap_MouseMove"
        MouseUp="myMap_MouseUp">
        <m:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems" ItemsSource="{Binding FieldList}">
            <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <m:MapPolyline
                        Fill="Aqua"
                        Locations="{Binding LocList}"
                        Stroke="ForestGreen"
                        StrokeDashArray="2 2"
                        StrokeThickness="5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl>

    </m:Map>
    <Button
        x:Name="ButtonAddingField"
        Height="75"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        Command="{Binding AddFieldCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ViewFieldList, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

View - MapHandle.cs

```
public partial class MapHandle
{
    public List<MapPolyline> ViewFieldList { get; set; } = new List<MapPolyline>();


    public MapHandle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new FieldCollectionViewModel();
        ...
    }
}
```

But! If I add something to the Map(in UI), for example, Pushpin through the left mouse button (**myMap.Children.Add()**), then Map will pull everything from the model. How can I fix it?

And why is it going on?

Comment: It seems odd that you have a view model and a property in the UserControl that at the same time are used as binding sources. Besides that, there doesn't seem to be any code that sets the ViewFieldList property. How is this supposed to work? And as a note, using the view type MapPolyline in your model seems also odd.

Comment: ViewFieldList can change as much as you like. When a button is clicked, the ViewModel displays it and updates the model. It is needed only for this and is not used anywhere else.
I change MapPolyline to LocationsCollection, but right now it doen't matter(